# How to make MinGW to treat texts like "text" as const char*

Tags: c++, c, string, char, mingw

AFAIK, after upgrading to *MinGW 4.4.** some time ago all of my literally written strings (like `"i'm the string"`) are treated as of the type `std::string`. Is there any command line option to make MinGW treat them as `const char*` as it was before?

Comment: Could you give an example? I think something is going wrong in your code.

Comment: Yes, example would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are per default `char *` / `char[]` in C / C++, only if you explicit say its a `std::string` you'll get those.

**Example:**

```
std::cout << "first:\t" << typeid("aa").name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "second:\t" << typeid(std::string("a")).name() << std::endl;
```

**Output:**

```
first:  A3_c
second: Ss
```

**Result:**

- first:  a `char` array with length of 3 (= 2 chars + end)
- second: is a `std::string`

As you can see, if you write `"abc"` you **wont** get a `std::string`.

**But:** if you write `std::string str = "abc"` you get a `std::string` because the asignment operator (`=`) is used: `string& operator= (const char* s)`